# Centos6 and PHP with Suhosin

Tags: centos, php

I'm setting up a webserver that's going to be apache + PHP. This is going to be migrated from Gentoo. In gentoo it was pretty easy to include Suhosin since it was just a useflag and a package. In CentOS you need to compile form source manually (download patches and so on).

IS there a better way to do this? Perhaps a repository that maintains a PHP package compiled with suhosin? I'm lazy and I don't like the current way to do it. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/redhat/6/x86_64/RPMS/ Make sure all the php modules you are going to user are there. You cannot mix RHEL PHP modules with the Atomic Corp PHP.